# How to use gtk_label_set_text()

Tags: gtk, glade

I am making a GUI using Glade and Gtk in which I am using label to display values of parameters. I have two variables x and y and they have values like 254 and 321 respectively. I want to display them as 254.321 . In normal printf, it is easy to do.

- But how can I do this in gtk_label_set_text function?
- Is there any way so that values which is displayed in gtk label can be updated automatically continuously?

I am using `sprintf` function first to change them from `int` to `string`.

Comment: Under what conditions do the values change? And what programming language do you use? The answers will affect my own.

Comment: I am using C language. Actually first has been done, I am just worried about how to update values automatically in gtk label.?

Comment: @AbhinavRawat When you want to update the values? Depend on any event or what ? This needs to be clear first then only member can provide you answer.

Comment: I have made functions for different values and I am calling that functions in button handler. So when I click the button, values get displayed on label, when I again click it, label updates with new values. So in order to update values i'll have to keep on clicking. I want it to update automatically, how to do this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a g_timeout_add_seconds to run in background so you can update/check whatever you want in every 'x' seconds; and for the sprintf, I recommend the glib wrapper function called g_strdup_printf.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, this g_timeout_add_seconds will just provide a delay.what I want is that my values should be  updated automatically on the label. right now whenever I click the button, it is getting updated but I want this thing to be done automatically. Is there any function for that or any other way pls help. Thanks.!

Comment: Yup, a bit wrong...if you read the documents it says runs *internally*, meaning runs in the background like running a program asynchronously unless the callback returns *G_SOURCE_REMOVE*, you should read the documents and search for examples and you'll see that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks it is working. But now how to stop it. I want it to stop when I press stop button. I have tried with different things but its not working. Please help thanks!

Comment: To stop the timeout use [g_source_remove](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-remove), but in order to use it, you must get the id, AKA the return value from g_timeout_add_seconds or g_timeout_add. Easy :)